# Grab my monthly bill via AWS api

Tags: amazon-web-services

I can't figure out how to make a simple call to display how much I owe Amazon for the month. Just want to display it for this internal dashboard I'm building. Any ideas? I'm not using cloudwatch

Answer (score 0):

You should follow these directions:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/about/programaccess.html

To tell AWS you would like your monthly bills dropped into an S3 bucket that you supply. Once its turned on, you can use the S3 API to read/download the bill and display it on your dashboard.

There is no 'real-time' billing API that I am aware of (kind of surprising given the technical sophistication of AWS).